# Opentelemetry with Prometheus - Metric Data points / scrapes missing

Tags: prometheus, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

Our Set-up in Kubernetes is as follows:

Opentelemetry agent (both java and python used and metrics from both have the same issue)

Opentelemetry-collector - version 0.77.0 (we previously were on 0.72.0 and that had the same problem)
It's using the otlp receiver, like this:

```
    otlp:
      protocols:
        grpc:
          endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
        http:
          endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318
```

It has the following processors configured:

```
  processors:
    memory_limiter:
      limit_mib: 4000
      spike_limit_mib: 800
      check_interval: 1s
    batch:
      send_batch_size: 10000
      send_batch_max_size: 11000
      timeout: 10s
    #Delete unnecessary attributes from our metrics
    resource:
      attributes:
        - key: telemetry.sdk.name
          action: delete
        - key: telemetry.sdk.version
          action: delete
        - key: telemetry.sdk.language
          action: delete
        - key: telemetry.auto.version
          action: delete
        - key: container.id
          action: delete
        - key: process.command.args
          action: delete
    k8sattributes/default:
```

Previously we had none of these processors configured and the problem was exactly the same

the opentelemetry collector has the prometheus exporter set like this:

```
  exporters:
    prometheus:
      endpoint: "0.0.0.0:9464"
      resource_to_telemetry_conversion:
        enabled: true
      enable_open_metrics: true
      namespace: prometheus
```

and then servicemonitors configured like this:

```
serviceMonitor:
  enabled: true
  metricsEndpoints:
    - port: metrics
      interval: 15s
  prometheusMetricsEndpoints:
    - port: app-metrics
      interval: 15s
      honorLabels: true
```

Then finally we have prometheus which scrapes for these metrics based on those servicemonitors and Grafana to visualise everything.

The problem we have is that for some of our metrics we randomly see that datapoints are missing... we usually get a datapoint every 15 seconds but sometimes it's just not there, here are some examples:

for the **logback_events_total** metric we see many empty datapoints:
[image: screenshot of logback_events_total metric showing missing datapoints]

and another example with **http_server_requests_milliseconds_count**
this time zoomed in a bit more to make it more clear showing points only, no lines:
[image: screenshot of http_server_requests_milliseconds_count showing missing datapoints]

in this one you can clearly see we get a point every 15 seconds but sometimes we miss one or two of these points.

I have looked at the metrics for machine_scrape_error and container_scrape_error and as you can see there are no dropped data points but more importantly no scrape errors being reported

[image: screenshot showing scrape error metrics]

This problem seems to **only happen for Counter based metrics**... for others we don't seem to get this problem at all (e.g jvm_threads_live).
Our Opentelemetry collector pod is only using roughly 10% CPU and 20% memory
Our prometheus is scaled to 6 pods with resource usage well under 50% of the requested amount.

I am running out of ideas about what could cause this, I understand that a few dropped scrapes is normal but this seems like more than would be acceptable.
We have tried turning on debug logs but haven't found anything useful in the logs.
I assume these data points could be going missing at different points along the way (agent, collector or prometheus). Does anyone have any advice about how to start tracking this down?

Adding another graph as it was mentioned in the comments:
scrape duration seconds plotted alongside another metric that was dropping data points:
[image: scrape duration seconds plotted alongside another metric that was dropping data points]
scrape duration seconds is the green line with no gaps

Edit: 30th May 2023
Still having the same issue, after enabling error logs on the otel collector we are seeing lines like these:

```
* collected metric prometheus_http_server_duration_milliseconds label:<name:"framework" value:"spring" > label:<name:"host_arch" value:"amd64" > label:<name:"host_name" value:"service-name-bf77bcc49-9dmh9" > label:<name:"http_method" value:"GET" > label:<name:"http_route" value:"/v1/vins/licenseplate/{licensePlateValue}/country/{country}/latest" > label:<name:"http_scheme" value:"http" > label:<name:"http_status_code" value:"204" > label:<name:"job" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_deployment_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_namespace_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_node_name" value:"ip-10-11-22-89.eu-central-1.compute.internal" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_ip" value:"10.11.20.233" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_name" value:"service-name-bf77bcc49-9dmh9" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_start_time" value:"2023-05-30 12:02:56 +0000 UTC" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_uid" value:"f3b6ef2e-31f5-4f4e-871a-ed34acfc247a" > label:<name:"label_team" value:"team-name" > label:<name:"net_host_name" value:"service-name-svc.service-name" > label:<name:"net_protocol_name" value:"http" > label:<name:"net_protocol_version" value:"1.1" > label:<name:"os_description" value:"Linux 5.15.90" > label:<name:"os_type" value:"linux" > label:<name:"process_command_args" value:"[\"/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java\",\"-XX:+UseSerialGC\",\"-Dopentelemetry.environment=development\",\"-javaagent:/opentelemetry/opentelemetry.jar\",\"-jar\",\"/app/service-name-fa541655.jar\"]" > label:<name:"process_executable_path" value:"/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java" > label:<name:"process_pid" value:"1" > label:<name:"process_runtime_description" value:"Eclipse Adoptium OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 19.0.2+7" > label:<name:"process_runtime_name" value:"OpenJDK Runtime Environment" > label:<name:"process_runtime_version" value:"19.0.2+7" > label:<name:"service_name" value:"service-name" > histogram:<sample_count:12 sample_sum:3068.996335 bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:0 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:5 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:10 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:25 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:50 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:75 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:100 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:250 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:500 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:750 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:1000 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:2500 > bucket:<cumulative_count:12 upper_bound:5000 > bucket:<cumulative_count:12 upper_bound:7500 > bucket:<cumulative_count:12 upper_bound:10000 > >  has help "The duration of the inbound HTTP request" but should have "measures the duration of the inbound HTTP request"
* collected metric prometheus_jvm_threads_states label:<name:"host_arch" value:"amd64" > label:<name:"host_name" value:"5b8bfdc684-29xd5" > label:<name:"job" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_deployment_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_namespace_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_node_name" value:"ip-10-11-15-117.eu-central-1.compute.internal" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_ip" value:"10.11.11.123" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_name" value:"service-name-5b8bfdc684-29xd5" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_start_time" value:"2023-05-30 12:45:54 +0000 UTC" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_uid" value:"bcc28b31-7026-47d0-bf89-e996e8b138a2" > label:<name:"label_team" value:"team-name" > label:<name:"process_runtime_name" value:"OpenJDK Runtime Environment" > label:<name:"process_runtime_version" value:"17.0.6+10" > label:<name:"service_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"state" value:"terminated" > gauge:<value:0 >  has help "The current number of threads having NEW state" but should have "The current number of threads"
* collected metric prometheus_http_server_duration_milliseconds label:<name:"host_arch" value:"amd64" > label:<name:"host_name" value:"74f9654b8-nkpdn" > label:<name:"http_method" value:"GET" > label:<name:"http_route" value:"/status" > label:<name:"http_scheme" value:"http" > label:<name:"http_status_code" value:"200" > label:<name:"job" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_deployment_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_namespace_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_node_name" value:"ip-10-11-20-192.eu-central-1.compute.internal" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_ip" value:"10.11.18.204" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_name" value:"service-name-74f9654b8-nkpdn" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_start_time" value:"2023-05-30 04:50:43 +0000 UTC" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_uid" value:"402efd2d-1daf-4672-b3cf-535a8f76d52a" > label:<name:"net_host_name" value:"10.11.18.204" > label:<name:"net_host_port" value:"8080" > label:<name:"net_protocol_name" value:"http" > label:<name:"net_protocol_version" value:"1.1" > label:<name:"os_description" value:"Linux 5.15.90" > label:<name:"os_type" value:"linux" > label:<name:"process_command_args" value:"[\"/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java\",\"-Xms512m\",\"-Xmx512m\",\"-Dnewrelic.environment=qa\",\"-javaagent:/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar\",\"org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher\"]" > label:<name:"process_executable_path" value:"/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java" > label:<name:"process_pid" value:"1" > label:<name:"process_runtime_description" value:"Eclipse Adoptium OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.6+10" > label:<name:"process_runtime_name" value:"OpenJDK Runtime Environment" > label:<name:"process_runtime_version" value:"17.0.6+10" > label:<name:"service_name" value:"tom" > histogram:<sample_count:1 sample_sum:701.935696 bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:0 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:5 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:10 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:25 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:50 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:75 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:100 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:250 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:500 > bucket:<cumulative_count:1 upper_bound:750 > bucket:<cumulative_count:1 upper_bound:1000 > bucket:<cumulative_count:1 upper_bound:2500 > bucket:<cumulative_count:1 upper_bound:5000 > bucket:<cumulative_count:1 upper_bound:7500 > bucket:<cumulative_count:1 upper_bound:10000 > >  has help "The duration of the inbound HTTP request" but should have "measures the duration of the inbound HTTP request"
```

This would suggest a mis-match between the description of the metric being received and the actual spec of that metric?

but, it seems strange that this would only be for some data points in a metric and not every one... does this help to narrow down the issue

Comment: what does the `scrape_duration_seconds` metric from prometheus look like? occasionally failed scrapes can be due to scrape timeouts.

Comment: thanks for replying @jaronoff97. I've added the scrape duration seconds metric in another screenshot at the end of my question

Comment: checked a few more metrics that could be relavent:
otelcol_processor_dropped_metric_points &
otelcol_processor_refused_metric_points. They are both constantly at 0

Comment: Try to use latest otel collector and set `metric_expiration: 2m` explicitly. How whole otel collector config looks like? Is there any processor?

Comment: hi @JanGaraj. Thanks for looking and for your suggestion, I will try it when I'm back at work on Monday. I have added the details of our processors into my original question. We are on version 0.77.0 of the collector, we were previously on 0.72.0... both versions had the same problems. just an added note: this is our first attempt at using prometheus + otel collector so it's not like this worked before then suddenly broke

Comment: I've tried setting metric_expiration: 2m but unfortunately it hasn't helped

Comment: Next suite of questions: 
* are your collectors up and healthy consistently?
* are you seeing any restarts?

It's possible that your collectors are dying and you are running in to issues with start times, which is a known frustration with prometheus/otel. See here [1] for more detail

[1] https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/be1f5653a7b1badd06b408d20f1ef8c32e9d1626/specification/metrics/data-model.md#cumulative-streams-handling-unknown-start-time

Comment: Hi @jaronoff97 . We aren't seeing any restarts on the collector (currently it's just a single pod) and it's resource usage is only around 20% of the request

Comment: @JanGaraj  - I have added some error logs that I found to the end of my original post, does this help narrow down the isssue, do you have any more thoughts?

Comment: @jaranoff97 - I have added some error logs that I found to the end of my original post, does this help narrow down the isssue, do you have any more thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I have a "fix" for this, it feels a bit like a workaround so I won't mark the question as answered...

It was these errors that were relevant for the missing data points:

```
* collected metric prometheus_http_server_duration_milliseconds label:<name:"framework" value:"spring" > label:<name:"host_arch" value:"amd64" > label:<name:"host_name" value:"service-name-bf77bcc49-9dmh9" > label:<name:"http_method" value:"GET" > label:<name:"http_route" value:"/v1/vins/licenseplate/{licensePlateValue}/country/{country}/latest" > label:<name:"http_scheme" value:"http" > label:<name:"http_status_code" value:"204" > label:<name:"job" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_deployment_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_namespace_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_node_name" value:"ip-10-11-22-89.eu-central-1.compute.internal" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_ip" value:"10.11.20.233" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_name" value:"service-name-bf77bcc49-9dmh9" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_start_time" value:"2023-05-30 12:02:56 +0000 UTC" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_uid" value:"f3b6ef2e-31f5-4f4e-871a-ed34acfc247a" > label:<name:"label_team" value:"team-name" > label:<name:"net_host_name" value:"service-name-svc.service-name" > label:<name:"net_protocol_name" value:"http" > label:<name:"net_protocol_version" value:"1.1" > label:<name:"os_description" value:"Linux 5.15.90" > label:<name:"os_type" value:"linux" > label:<name:"process_command_args" value:"[\"/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java\",\"-XX:+UseSerialGC\",\"-Dopentelemetry.environment=development\",\"-javaagent:/opentelemetry/opentelemetry.jar\",\"-jar\",\"/app/service-name-fa541655.jar\"]" > label:<name:"process_executable_path" value:"/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java" > label:<name:"process_pid" value:"1" > label:<name:"process_runtime_description" value:"Eclipse Adoptium OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 19.0.2+7" > label:<name:"process_runtime_name" value:"OpenJDK Runtime Environment" > label:<name:"process_runtime_version" value:"19.0.2+7" > label:<name:"service_name" value:"service-name" > histogram:<sample_count:12 sample_sum:3068.996335 bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:0 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:5 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:10 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:25 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:50 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:75 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:100 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:250 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:500 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:750 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:1000 > bucket:<cumulative_count:11 upper_bound:2500 > bucket:<cumulative_count:12 upper_bound:5000 > bucket:<cumulative_count:12 upper_bound:7500 > bucket:<cumulative_count:12 upper_bound:10000 > >  has help "The duration of the inbound HTTP request" but should have "measures the duration of the inbound HTTP request"
* collected metric prometheus_jvm_threads_states label:<name:"host_arch" value:"amd64" > label:<name:"host_name" value:"5b8bfdc684-29xd5" > label:<name:"job" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_deployment_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_namespace_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_node_name" value:"ip-10-11-15-117.eu-central-1.compute.internal" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_ip" value:"10.11.11.123" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_name" value:"service-name-5b8bfdc684-29xd5" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_start_time" value:"2023-05-30 12:45:54 +0000 UTC" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_uid" value:"bcc28b31-7026-47d0-bf89-e996e8b138a2" > label:<name:"label_team" value:"team-name" > label:<name:"process_runtime_name" value:"OpenJDK Runtime Environment" > label:<name:"process_runtime_version" value:"17.0.6+10" > label:<name:"service_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"state" value:"terminated" > gauge:<value:0 >  has help "The current number of threads having NEW state" but should have "The current number of threads"
* collected metric prometheus_http_server_duration_milliseconds label:<name:"host_arch" value:"amd64" > label:<name:"host_name" value:"74f9654b8-nkpdn" > label:<name:"http_method" value:"GET" > label:<name:"http_route" value:"/status" > label:<name:"http_scheme" value:"http" > label:<name:"http_status_code" value:"200" > label:<name:"job" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_deployment_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_namespace_name" value:"service-name" > label:<name:"k8s_node_name" value:"ip-10-11-20-192.eu-central-1.compute.internal" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_ip" value:"10.11.18.204" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_name" value:"service-name-74f9654b8-nkpdn" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_start_time" value:"2023-05-30 04:50:43 +0000 UTC" > label:<name:"k8s_pod_uid" value:"402efd2d-1daf-4672-b3cf-535a8f76d52a" > label:<name:"net_host_name" value:"10.11.18.204" > label:<name:"net_host_port" value:"8080" > label:<name:"net_protocol_name" value:"http" > label:<name:"net_protocol_version" value:"1.1" > label:<name:"os_description" value:"Linux 5.15.90" > label:<name:"os_type" value:"linux" > label:<name:"process_command_args" value:"[\"/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java\",\"-Xms512m\",\"-Xmx512m\",\"-Dnewrelic.environment=qa\",\"-javaagent:/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar\",\"org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher\"]" > label:<name:"process_executable_path" value:"/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java" > label:<name:"process_pid" value:"1" > label:<name:"process_runtime_description" value:"Eclipse Adoptium OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.6+10" > label:<name:"process_runtime_name" value:"OpenJDK Runtime Environment" > label:<name:"process_runtime_version" value:"17.0.6+10" > label:<name:"service_name" value:"tom" > histogram:<sample_count:1 sample_sum:701.935696 bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:0 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:5 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:10 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:25 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:50 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:75 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:100 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:250 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:500 > bucket:<cumulative_count:1 upper_bound:750 > bucket:<cumulative_count:1 upper_bound:1000 > bucket:<cumulative_count:1 upper_bound:2500 > bucket:<cumulative_count:1 upper_bound:5000 > bucket:<cumulative_count:1 upper_bound:7500 > bucket:<cumulative_count:1 upper_bound:10000 > >  has help "The duration of the inbound HTTP request" but should have "measures the duration of the inbound HTTP request"
```

For whatever reason that I still don't understand, some of the data points were being received with descriptions that didn't match what was expected.
In the metrics endpoint you can see what is expected by looking at the help text:

```
# HELP http_server_duration_milliseconds The duration of the inbound HTTP request
# TYPE http_server_duration_milliseconds histogram
```

For each different error I saw in the logs, I was able to use the transform processor to ensure that the description always matches the Help text:

```
    transform:
      error_mode: ignore
      metric_statements:
        - context: metric
          statements:
            - set(description, "The duration of the inbound HTTP request") where name == "http.server.duration"
            - set(description, "The current number of threads having NEW state") where name == "jvm.threads.states"
            - set(description, "The number of concurrent HTTP requests that are currently in-flight") where name == "http.server.active_requests" 
            - set(description, "") where name == "http.server.requests"
            - set(description, "") where name == "http.server.requests.max"
            - set(description, "Number of log events that were enabled by the effective log level") where name == "logback.events"
```

I no longer have any errors or dropped data points